# Ionic Framework Hackishly hide inputs error when archiving in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, ionic-framework

I have written an app in xCode, compiled it and sent it successfully into both the Apple Store and Google Play.

This was several months ago.

I now have been asked to update the app and when I compile in xCode I get an error message pertaining to the 'IonicKeyboard.m' file saying that the property 'HackishlyHidesInput AccessoryView' not found on object of type 'UIView *'.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be done:

- Make sure you are NOT using the plugin `com.ionic.keyboard` and instead are using `ionic-plugin-keyboard`.
- The version of `ionic-plugin-keyboard` must be at least `1.0.8` to be fixed.